# Run application on win8 login screen

Tags: c++, windows, authentication

I need to run my app (some kind of on-screen keyboard) on login screen (before login, to help enter password). I can sign code when needed.

EDIT: I prefer to schedule app running from my manager app code.

Comment: I decided to use widows service with input device driver.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant search term is "Input Method Editor" or IME. Microsoft has [released guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967425.aspx) how these should work, and then it is possible to choose them from the login screen.